# Load trained model on another machine - fastai, torch, huggingface

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, fast-ai

I am using fastai with pytorch to fine tune XLMRoberta from huggingface.
I've trained the model and everything is fine on the machine where I trained it.

But when I try to load the model on another machine I get `OSError - Not Found - No such file or directory` pointing to `.cache/torch/transformers/`. The issue is the path of a `vocab_file`.

I've used fastai's [Learner.export](https://docs.fast.ai/learner.html#Learner.export) to export the model in `.pkl` file, but I don't believe that issue is related to fastai since I found [the same issue](https://github.com/flairNLP/flair/issues/1747) appearing in flairNLP.

It appears that the path to the cache folder, where the vocab_file is stored during the training, is embedded in the `.pkl` file:
[image]

The error comes from transformer's [XLMRobertaTokenizer](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/tokenization_xlm_roberta.html) `__setstate__`:

```py
def __setstate__(self, d):
    self.__dict__ = d
    self.sp_model = spm.SentencePieceProcessor()
    self.sp_model.Load(self.vocab_file)
```

which tries to load the vocab_file using the path from the file.

I've tried patching this method using:

```py
pretrained_model_name = "xlm-roberta-base"
vocab_file = XLMRobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name).vocab_file

def _setstate(self, d):
    self.__dict__ = d
    self.sp_model = spm.SentencePieceProcessor()
    self.sp_model.Load(vocab_file)

XLMRobertaTokenizer.__setstate__ = MethodType(_setstate, XLMRobertaTokenizer(vocab_file))
```

And that successfully loaded the model but caused other problems like missing model attributes and other unwanted issues.

Can someone please explain why is the path embedded inside the file, is there a way to configure it without reexporting the model or if it has to be reexported how to configure it dynamically using fastai, torch and huggingface.

Comment: `.cache/torch/transformers` is the default cache location and should not be used to load models. I am actually not completely sure what you are trying to do, but when fastai (have never worked with it) has an export, why do you not use the corresponding import? The proper way to store a hugginface model and tokenizer, is to use `save_pretrained(location)`. You can later load the tokenizer and the model from this loaction with `from_pretrained`.

Comment: @cronoik Thank you for the comment. Yes, I'm aware of `pretrained` functions in huggingface but all the libraries are intertwined together and I would have to overwrite certain parts of fastai's export. Anyway, I'll take a closer look and see what I can do, but for now I solved this by creating a Docker image.

Comment: I asked you that before, but does fastai not have an import function?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error. I had fine tuned XLMRoberta on downstream classification task with fastai version = 1.0.61. I'm loading the model inside docker.

I'm not sure about why the path is embedded, but I found a workaround. Posting for future readers who might be looking for workaround as retraining is usually not possible.

1. I created /home/.cache/torch/transformer/ inside the docker image.

> ```
> RUN mkdir -p /home/<username>/.cache/torch/transformers
> ```

3. Copied the files (which were not found in docker) from my local /home/.cache/torch/transformer/ to docker image /home/.cache/torch/transformer/

> ```
>  COPY filename:/home/<username>/.cache/torch/transformers/filename
> ```